# How can I escape underscores in Django's field lookups?

Tags: django

By default, Django cannot support trailing underscores in field names because it messes up [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups). Unfortunately, I've found myself in a situation where the Postgres table was created *without* using Django and now I have to do the following:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(**{field + '__icontains': value})
```

This `field` could have an underscore. How do I tell Django to ignore the first of the triple underscores and find the field? It clearly knows about the field because it shows it as an option in the error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'ccc' into field. Choices are: _bbb, aa_a, ccc_

But I have not found any way to force `filter` to do what I want. Is there a syntax that let's me explicitly specify field name and lookup?

Comment: manually altering column names in postgres is not an option?

Comment: @at14: No, not in this case. We are using foreign data wrappers to bring tables in from external databases and part of my requirement is that I can't modify the table schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the field an appropriate name in the model, and use [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#db-column) to refer to the underlying name.

```
ccc = models.CharField(..., db_column="real_name_")
```